# Black hole entangled with the cosmological horizon

Tags: black-holes, quantum-gravity, quantum-entanglement, event-horizon

Maldacena and Susskind recently proposed a interesting and very suggestive duality between entanglement and topological identification: http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0533

But are such ideas applicable to horizons in general? Can I entangle a black hole horizon, with, say, a Rindler horizon as seen by an accelerated observer? Can I entangle a black hole with our cosmological horizon?

Are these in principle, physically possible operations?

**Note:** this question might be part of a multi-part question

Comment: The identification of the ER bridge in the black hole geometry is so say that you have two states in the dual CFT on the black hole geometry which are entangled to each other. So if you were to have a bridge between the cosmological horizon and the black hole - what's the correct operator-state correspondence for a cosmological horizon?